# Which Machine Learning algorithm: Sorted list of tags given metadata?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, algorithms

Our system allows an admin to manage a database of university courses. These courses have multiple fields, like the department, a title, and a description.

I am adding the ability to add learning objectives to a course. To simplify the problem, let's say that learning objectives are just tags. Courses can have more than one learning objective associated with them. So a course like CHEM 101 might have "chemistry", "technology", "science", and several others.

Assuming I can reduce a course to a set of features, (using keywords/stemming/nlp, I suppose?), what kind of problem is this and what algorithm would you suggest? It seems very similar to a classification problem, but I want to provide a sorted list of suggestions with the most relevant at the top.

Answer (score 2):

This class of problem is known as [learning to rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank); it's one of the core tasks of information retrieval, e.g. what a search engine does, though your case is slightly different in terms of the relative numbers of objects and so on. There are many methods, overviewed e.g. in [the Approaches section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank#Approaches) of the linked Wikipedia article, most of which can probably apply to this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a defined set of tags, you can use a Rule-Based classifier. A Rule-Based classifier is a very primitive machine learning technique which works based on 'if' 'and' 'or' conditions.